# My menu broke others widgets

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I found some old left side menu and changed it to right side. Now I'm remaking Blog template and just noticed that my menu Script keep 'blocking' my new slider for posts and one more widget. Problem solve removing full menu script but this not an answer because i need this menu with click button with open and hide it.
Here is my test blog site http://testmebloggg.blogspot.com and here is JS of my menu :

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var body = $('body');
            $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function() {
                body.toggleClass('menu-open');
                return false;
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking"? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: some kind of broken widget but when u remove full script from menu widget all is ok. If it will help U id of slider is HTML2 and id of menu is HTML3

Comment: Bug make was:


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> cuz same thing was in both menu and the slider. Thanks for reply anyway. :)